# Incorrect position of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, position, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a `UIView` called `viewProgress`. It is the white box in the image. I want a circular progress bar, which is the green circle in the image. The progress bar should stay within the white box, but as you can see it is way off.

How do I make it stay inside the `viewProgress`?
Here you have my animation function:

```
func animateView() {

        let circle = viewProgress // viewProgress is a UIView

        var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circle.center, radius: circle.bounds.midX, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(3.0 * M_PI_2), clockwise: true)

        progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
        progressCircle.path = circlePath.CGPath
        progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 10.0

        circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 0.4
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false

        progressCircle.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "ani")
    }
```

And I'm just calling the function inside `viewDidLoad()`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically u have few problems:

1. incorrect position of your layer - frame should be equal to bounds of parent layer in parentView
2. you animation will play only once - if u want to make it infinite add something like `animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT`
3. to make sure that all size correct - in `layoutSubviews` recreate layers, with removing previously created one
4. `UIBezierPath(arcCenter...` will start path from `rightSide`, u can also use simpler variant like `UIBezierPath(ovalInRect`. With this in mind u also need to rotate layer for M_PI_2 if u want to make start of drawing in the very top of circle
5. U should also take in mind that with line width 10, half of u'r circle path will be catted by `clipSubviews` of parentView. To prevent this use modified parentLayer rect
6. U can also maybe want to improve visualization of `lineCap`, buy setting it to "round" style
7. `progressCircle.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "ani")` key for anim not required if u dont want to get completion event from animation - i your case i see there is no `delegate` and no `removeOnCompletion` flag setted to false, so make assumption that u don`t actually need it

Keeping this all in mind code can be like :

```
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)) // viewProgress is a UIView
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
view.addSubview(circle)

var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()
progressCircle.frame = view.bounds

let lineWidth:CGFloat = 10
let rectFofOval = CGRectMake(lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, circle.bounds.width - lineWidth, circle.bounds.height - lineWidth)

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rectFofOval)

progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
progressCircle.path = circlePath.CGPath
progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
progressCircle.lineWidth = 10.0
progressCircle.frame = view.bounds
progressCircle.lineCap = "round"

circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
circle.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(circle.transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1.1
animation.duration = 1
animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

progressCircle.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

and result actually like:

[image]

**Note:**
If u want to animate rotation of animated layer u should also add additional animation in to anim group

Comment: Worked like a charm! If I do not want the ends to be rounded off, how do I change that?

Comment: just remove `progressCircle.lineCap = "round"`